# Follow springs docs is failing to get working Tomcat 7 (it is Tomcat 8 again)

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7

I'm following spring instruction how to use Tomcat 7 instead of Tomcat 8
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-7-maven :

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.data.version>1.9.4.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
    <spring.batch.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    <spring.integration.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
    <spring.boot.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
</properties>

...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when running app it's still running on Tomcat 8:

```
o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
```

Also next dependencies are loaded to `lib` folder:

```
tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.5.4.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar
tomcat-juli-7.0.59.jar
```

What else to change to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the spring-boot-starter-parent as a parent dependency in you pom.xml? I think you maybe have to have that for the tomcat.version property to work on the spring-boot-starter-web dependency. Thats where the dependency-management for the starter-dependencies are. Otherwise it just take the latest version of tomcat inside the spring-boot-starter-web...

Comment: No, I have not used `spring-boot-starter-parent`. I also think in this direction. But it took version 8.5.4 when in nexus there are exists 9.0.0.  The only pom where explicit version 8.5.4 for tomcat is defined is `spring-boot-dependencies` but this file not even in dependency tree.

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.0.RELEASE` uses Tomcat 8.5.4 by default. If you want to override that and you're not using `spring-boot-starter-parent` you'll need to provide your own dependency management for Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Without Starter Parent:

```xml
<project>
    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- things you wanna override  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- pom -->
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You can see what happen in maven by **IntelliJ [Show Dependencies]**

[image]

Just use "tomcat.version", nothing happened in **IntelliJ [Show Dependencies]**, so I check what I should override in **Show Dependencies** and then override them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. exclude tomcat from spring-boot-starter-web dependency.
2. and declare a tomcat.version property and add tomcat related dependencies explicitly.

If you are using an IDE, eg. IntelliJ IDEA, and try to refresh Maven pom(there is an icon for this when you are in a pom.xml file), and rebuild your project to clean the cache in IDEs.

If you are using mvn command, try to clean and build it.

eg.

```sh
mvn clean package
```